# Python Numpy syntax: what does array index as two arrays separated by comma mean?

Tags: python, numpy

I don't understand array as index in Python Numpy.
For example, I have a 2d array A in Numpy

```
[[1,2,3]
 [4,5,6]
 [7,8,9]
 [10,11,12]]
```

What does A[[1,3], [0,1]] mean?

Comment: Have you tried, and studied the result?

Comment: or simply googled 'numpy indexing'?

Comment: I tried googling, but all tutorial are really long and I can't find out this exact syntax that I am looking for.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're looking for?

Comment: The answer is the exact thing I am looking for. I am trying to understand some code written by other people that has this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test it for yourself!

```
A = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
print(A)
>>> array([[ 0,  1,  2],
   [ 3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  7,  8],
   [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

By slicing the array the way you did ([docs to slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)), you'll get the first row, zero-th column element and the third row, first column element.

```
A[[1,3], [0,1]]
>>> array([ 3, 10])
```

I'd highly encourage you to play around with that a bit and have a look at the documentation and the examples.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your are creating a new array:

```
import numpy as np

A = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9],
     [10, 11, 12]]
A = np.array(A)

print(A[[1, 3], [0, 1]])
# [ 4 11]
```

See **Indexing, Slicing and Iterating** in the [tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating).

> Multidimensional arrays can have one index per axis. These indices are given in a tuple separated by commas

Quoting the doc:

```
def f(x,y):
    return 10*x+y

b = np.fromfunction(f, (5, 4), dtype=int)
print(b[2, 3])
# -> 23
```

You can also use a NumPy array as index of an array. See [Index arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) in the doc.

> NumPy arrays may be indexed with other arrays (or any other sequence- like object that can be converted to an array, such as lists, with the exception of tuples; see the end of this document for why this is). The use of index arrays ranges from simple, straightforward cases to complex, hard-to-understand cases. For all cases of index arrays, what is returned is a copy of the original data, not a view as one gets for slices.